# What does the ( ' > ) symbol mean in the command line in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, command-line

I'm new to sql and for some reason, the arrow symbol ( -> ) that I am used to seeing in teh command line, which mean it is ready for input, is now displayed as ( '> ) and it does not accept commands. What does it mean and how do I get back to ( -> ) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means that it is treating any input which follows as part of a string literal, until it encounters a(n unescaped) string termination quote `'` character.

This will have happened because you previously began the string literal with such a string termination quote character.  For example:

```
mysql> SELECT foo
    -> FROM   tbl
    -> WHERE  bar LIKE 'somestring
    '> this is still part of somestring'
    -> ;
```

Comment: Thank you. I added an unnecessary quotation mark in my statement.

Answer (score 2):

[find the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z6Jm.png)

use '/ command and press enter then it will go on next line starting with ->
then use ; and press enter.

it happens if there is unbalanced '(single quote) in query.

Comment: Please include the image in the post rather than linking to it.

Answer (score 1):

It means you have an incomplete query. Most likely it's something related to a missing quotation, semi-colon at the end, or parentheses aren't closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can exit the query with: '\c
Not sure what happens to the query but it gets you back to the mysql> prompt.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8ZNR.jpg)

As you can see, I encountered the same issue, the solution is :

type '> in the command line, then insert some command as I did(please refer to the picture attached), and then the new line starts.

Comment: Please do not post images of code, copy your code into the question with block code format:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask